# jQuery: Hide/Show Button and div on Submit

Tags: jquery, forms

When I submit my form I want the submit button to hide and then a div with a message to appear. Seems to be pretty basic but it's not working; the submit button doesn't disappear and the message div doesn't appear.

Is there something in the document or dom that prevents this from happening until the form is submitted? Or am I just overlooking something really easy?

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

<div id="spin"></div>

<script>

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // hide the submit button
    $('#submit').hide();

    // replace the submit button with a "message" button"
    $('#spin').html('<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp; Saving...</button>');

});

</script>
```

Comment: its working, check you add the jquery library or not.

Answer (score 3):

Its working fine, check you add the `jQuery` library or not

see [Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/dnmobn6k/)

Use of `this` is a good practice when the same selector use in the body of same event.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  // hide the submit button
  $(this).hide();
  // replace the submit button with a "message" button"
  $('#spin').html('<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp; Saving...</button>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code working fine just check that your jquery library it added well

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // hide the submit button
    $('#submit').hide();

    // replace the submit button with a "message" button"
    $('#spin').html('<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp; Saving...</button>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

<div id="spin"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, guys. I figured out what was happening: I needed to interrupt the submission of the form — show/hide the stuff — then continue submission of the form.

For anybody else who may stumble across this problem, this did the trick:

```
$('#form-post').unbind('submit').submit();
```

**Full example**

```
<form id="form-post">

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div id="spin"></div>

</form>


<script>

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    $(this).hide();

    $('#spin').html('<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>Saving...</button>');

    $('#form-post').unbind('submit').submit();
});

</script>
```

*Changed `$('#submit')` to `$(this)` as suggested by Frayne Konok.